# Orientation problem from inertial module LSM9DS1 Arduino

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, iot, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am working on a project where i have to determine position and rotation of an IoT object with accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. The goal is to show this object in a Unity3D virtual world.

To do this, i have an Arduino Nano 33 BLE that include a LSM9DS1 as inertial module.
So, i started to determine the rotation of my object. This link was very usefull : http://gilles.thebault.free.fr/spip.php?article32

That's the line for get the Y axis :
angle=0.98*(angle+float(gy)*0.01/131) + 0.02*atan2((double)ax,(double)az)*180/PI;

With this one, i can get X, Y and Z angles. When i try one by one axis orientation, all axis rotation are fine. The problem is when i use 2 axis or more at same time. For example, i use only X and Y axis. When i turn only X axis of 90°, Y axis turn of 90° too. This video will explain more accurately than words : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeuIuEcjUBc&feature=youtu.be

I searched lot of things to fix it but now, i have no more idea. Can anyone guide me?